# ORA-01031 after creating table (But only for a while)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm having some problems with oracle after creating a table. I have the proper permissions to create the table, but if I try to query immediately after creating it I get error ORA-01031 "Insufficient privileges".

However, if I wait a couple of hours then I have no problems querying it.

Any ideas what would cause this?

Comment: Are you creating the table in your own schema? are you sure no admin or script is granting you access behind the scenes?

Comment: This almost definitely belongs on [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/), *but* you need to improve it first. Create a test case that reproduces for you and can be run by others. If you can, test it on another database. Include both the sample and the results in the question, along with any findings about changes to your test case that change the behavior. Also, does "waiting a couple of hours" involve disconnecting and then connecting again? What happens if you reconnect immediately? A lot more detail is needed here.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need give privilege for selection data from created table for user that contains it. Use follow script:

```
grant select on <user>.created_table to <user>;
```

this script must run from user with admin grant.

Also you can give several options:

```
grant select, update, delete, insert on <user>.created_table to <user>;
```